# How to save the size of image in txt file with matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to find the size of an image (height, width, and area) and save the size value in txt file. I tried this command:

```
img = imread('TN4.jpg');
abu=rgb2gray(img);
imwrite(abu,'abu.jpg');
cb=imclearborder(abu); 
imwrite(cb,'cb.jpg')
thresh=graythresh(cb); 
b=im2bw(cb,thresh); 
imwrite(b,'b.jpg');
bw=bwareaopen(b,100);
bwfill=imfill(bw,'holes');
imwrite(bwfill,'bw.jpg');

s = regionprops(bwfill,'BoundingBox');
out = bsxfun(@times,img,uint8(bwfill));
objects=cell(numel(s),1);

for idx = 1:numel(s)

    bb=floor(s(idx).BoundingBox);

    objects{idx} = out(bb(2):bb(2)+bb(4), bb(1):bb(1)+bb(3),:);

end


k1=objects{1};
c1=rgb2gray(k1);
t1=graythresh(c1); 
biner1=im2bw(c1,t1); 
[height, width] = size(biner1);
a1 = bwarea(biner1);
h1=height(biner1);
w1=width(biner1);

X = [(h1);(w1);(a1)];
save datagrading.txt X -ascii
```

but i got warning massage

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> exercise at 35
h1=height(biner1);
```

can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height` and `width` are **scalars** yet (it looks like to me...) you are assuming that they are functions.... no they're not functions.  Just use `height` and `width` on its own and place it into your `X` matrix:

```
[height, width] = size(biner1);
a1 = bwarea(biner1);
%h1=height(biner1); %// Remove
%w1=width(biner1); %// Remove

X = [height;width;a1]; %// Change
save datagrading.txt X -ascii
```

---

Since you have multiple objects and you want to save the height, width and area of these objects, just loop over each one, find the quantities you desire, place them into an overall matrix and save it:

```
X = zeros(3, numel(objects));
for k = 1 : numel(objects)
    k1=objects{k}; %// Change
    c1=rgb2gray(k1);
    t1=graythresh(c1); 
    biner1=im2bw(c1,t1); 
    [height, width] = size(biner1);
    a1 = bwarea(biner1);
    X(:,k) = [height;width;a1];
end

save datagrading.txt X -ascii
```

`X` is now a `3 x s` matrix where `s` is the total number of objects you have.  Therefore, each column contains the height, width and area of each object.

Comment: thank you. it works.
but, as you can see, the commands applied only for one object in the image (k1=objects{1}) , while I have few objects. i intended to save all of  size data of the object in the image in the same txt as well. what should i do?

Comment: You can loop over each of the images then save the entire matrix. I'll edit my post.

Comment: excuse me @rayryeng, but can I ask another question? How to apply those comment if i have multiple images with multiple objects in it and I want to save those data  in one txt file? I tried but it only saved the current processed image data. Thank You

Comment: Use another loop to loop over each image.

Comment: Hey @rayryeng, I tried to make another loop but it didn't work. I got confused because I'm using image that attached into axes, there are 9 axes and I want to save all the data. Can you help me again? Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You declared

```
[height, width] = size(biner1);
```

So `height(biner1)` will refer to the `biner1`-th element of `height`, which is not existent.
Use `X = [(height);(width);(a1)];` instead.